# How can I do a subquery in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hello I need to do a query that counts the posts that have meta_key like status and meta_value like Unplaced, and the same post has a meta_key like issue_date and meta_value like a date between two days. For example, I have a table like this:

```
id_meta post_id meta_key   meta_valuue
      1       1 status     Unplaced
      2       1 issue_date 20160428
      3       2 status     VIP
      4       2 issue_date 20160428
      5       3 status     Placed
      6       3 issue_date 20160427
      7       4 status     Unplaced
      8       4 issue_date 20160420
```

I want that the query only returns 1 because only one post has status Unplaced and the issue_date between 21 and 28. The query that I wrote is:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_var(" 
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM wp_posts
     , wp_postmeta 
 WHERE meta.key = 'status' 
   AND meta_value LIKE '%Unplaced%' 
   AND post_id = ID 
   AND post_status <> 'trash' 
   AND post_id IN ( SELECT post_id 
                      FROM wp_postmeta 
                     WHERE meta_key = 'issue_date' 
                       AND meta_value >= '20160421' 
                       AND meta_value <= '20160428')
");
```

I need that the posts don't be in trash.

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a meta_query args and pass to WP_Query like this

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'status',
            'value'   => 'Unplaced',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'issue_date',
            'value'   => array( '2016-04-21', '2016-04-28' ),
            'type'    => 'date',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

//Then get count like this
$query->found_posts;
```

The type `DATE` should be in the format YYYY-MM-DD for compare value `BETWEEN` to work.

Read more about WP_Query [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and about `$found_posts` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties)

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT s.post_id
     , s.meta_value status
     , i.meta_value issue_date 
  FROM wp_posts s 
  JOIN wp_posts i 
    ON i.post_id = s.post_id 
 WHERE s.meta_key = 'status' 
   AND s.meta_value = 'Unplaced' 
   AND i.meta_key = 'issue_date' 
   AND i.meta_value BETWEEN '20160421' AND '20160428';
```